# Odoo PoS scan barcode internal reference

Tags: javascript, odoo, barcode, point-of-sale, ean-13

I'd like to enter barcodes in the internal reference field and scan those in the PoS.
I saw in the code that it should already do this, but whenever I put an EAN13 barcode in the internal reference (default_code) field it is not recognized by the PoS.

I placed a print of the .encoding in my code, which always returns 'EAN13', any ideas how this is determined? Or how I can fix this, thanks!

Views.JS code from the point_of_sale:

```
 scan_product: function(parsed_code){
        var self = this;
        var selectedOrder = this.get('selectedOrder');
        console.log(parsed_code.encoding)
        console.log(parsed_code)
        if(parsed_code.encoding === 'ean13'){
            var product = this.db.get_product_by_ean13(parsed_code.base_code);
        }else if(parsed_code.encoding === 'reference'){
            var product = this.db.get_product_by_reference(parsed_code.code);
        }

        if(!product){
            return false;
        }
```